# How to align 'price' and 'add to cart' button in the same row at Shop Page of Woocommerce?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to know how can I align 'price' and 'add to cart' button in the same row at SHOP PAGE of woocommerce.

[image: sample image attached]

Comment: Go to the parent element and make it display: flex; Then go to the two child's and set width to 50% for both elements.

Comment: Is there a way to make it with exact css code that I can insert to Additional CSS section of the theme customizer? Because I don't know how to go to Parent and then child.

Comment: I'm currently not on my computer. You can check the DOM with the developer tools to see the layout. Maybe you have a link to your website for me? So I verify it directly on your page

Comment: I am working at local environment Mr. Jo. (theme: Storefront Theme of Woocommerce) and fopenly speaking I have no coding knowladge, I just try to find that code and insert the Additional CSS section of the theme.

Comment: Is there any fits once for all CSS Code for this Mr Jo and Mr Loic?

Comment: It can't work with you CSS. I've checked the Storefront template and you need to rebuild the part with the price and the button. Let me see what I can do for you.

Comment: Mr Jo; so this is not possible to do at Storefront? the below code is working at desktop+phone screen but not at tablet view.

Comment: In your case I would use a two column layout on iPad and Mobile because when you have prices above 200.000,00 or whatever, the place could be not enough to display it on a small device. Whats your opinion about this? Have you thought about this?

Comment: I tried with 2 column but still tablet view looks bad. At tablet view, the space between price and add to cart button is very big. As you said once the price increase, the space won't be enough. I drop it; it needs to be code from scratch.

Comment: You need to rebuild the layout as I already told. If you wait until tomorrow when I'm back in the office I can provide you a full working example. I've worked so much last weekend that I need to give me a bit of a pause :) hope you understand this.

Comment: Mr Jo, I am sorry If i wrote any wrong, I m new in this platform and trying to learn as a non-techy wordpress enthusiast. Yes sure take your time sir. I am checking this question time to time.

Comment: To prepare my answer, you can create already create a woocommerce folder in your child theme (if you have one)

Comment: I have created pluging to insert php code instead of messing theme functions.php file. I already add few codes and i saw I did it right; pluging works. You mean this? Mr. Jo.

Comment: So you don't working with a child theme? E.G. see this website: https://learnwoo.com/create-woocommerce-storefront-child-theme/. If you don't have this, I would really recommend this because otherwise you can't safely change the WooCommerce templates at all. With other words, my solution can't work.

Comment: Mr Jo, I just made a Child theme by using 'child theme wizard' plugin sir. I am ready to attack my theme's CSS now :)

Comment: So create a folder names woocommerce in your child theme. I'll show you the next steps in my answer tomorrow.

Comment: What other folders do I need Mr Jo sir? the child theme has styles.css and functions.php . Mr Jo you can reply tomorrow sir.

Comment: You just need the woocommerce folder there. My answer comes today.

Comment: Mr Jo; I just saw your post at below. I am looking now immedietly. please give me time to handle this.

Comment: Does it work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following css in your additional css

```
.products span.price{
    float:left;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}
.products a.button.add_to_cart_button{
    float: right;
}
```

I have checked and it's working. You can check this screenshot

[image]

Comment: Using float isn't that good in a responsive layout but with CSS this is the best solution. If you want to use flex, you need to change the template.

Comment: At Storefront Shop Page; this CSS Code worked well. BUT If you have 'Sale' badge at the product, the 'Sale' badge pushes the 'Add to cart' button down and look weird. [link](https://i.postimg.cc/FFPHFQFJ/With-Sale-Badge-Look.jpg). I hope you see image at the link.

Comment: Mr Jo; I changed the theme from Storefront to Astra however this CSS Code didn't work at all. Mr Melvin, then I tried with Strorefront again but this time with Tablet view/layout; and it didnt look good too. It looks good only at Desktop view + Phone view without Sale badge.

Comment: I can remove or change the 'sale' badge placing BUT how will I make this CSS Code look good at tablet view? (at desktop and phone view; the code works good)

Comment: @br76 This is the basic one which will work on storefront with default settings. If you have sales badge this may not work as html changes. Also this maynot work for other themes. You have to customise this code for other views

Comment: Mr Melvin; I will use this code as a base format. Will check for other themes if necessary but at least; we saw it works at Mobile+desktop.

Comment: @br76 i can check it in tablet mode in chrome if you need. So that you can accept this as answer. Also please tell me if you need css for any particular theme

Comment: Mr Melvin, I will not continue with storefront so you dont need to try for tablet view. In the mean time if I need css for particular theme then I messege here sir.

Comment: ok. Thanks for the update. It would be helpful if you could upvote my answer for my efforts@br76

Comment: I upvoted Mr Melvin sir. But still shows 1 number. But I upvoted sir.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go. I assume that you've created a `woocommerce` folder in your installation. Go now to `plugins > woocommerce > templates` and copy the file `content-product.php` directly into your `woocommerce` folder of your child theme. The structure needs to look like this after the step above:

```
- themes
  - Storefront
  - YourChildTheme
    - functions.php
    - woocommerce <- you need create this folder
        - content-product.php
```

When this is done, you need to open the copied file. Replace the content of the file with this content and save the file:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying product content within loops
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/content-product.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.4.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

global $product;

// Ensure visibility.
if ( empty( $product ) || ! $product->is_visible() ) {
    return;
}
?>
<li <?php wc_product_class(); ?>>
    <?php
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' );

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_title - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
     */
    ?>
    <div class="shop-loop-item-details-wrapper">
        <?php 
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close - 5
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart - 10
     */
    //do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
    ?>
</li>
```

After that, open the **Customizer** and go to the **Additional CSS** section. Paste this here into the field and publish the page:

```
.shop-loop-item-details-wrapper {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
            flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
        justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    padding-top: 8px;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.shop-loop-item-details-wrapper .woocommerce-loop-product__link {
    margin-right: 8px;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
            flex: 1;
}

.shop-loop-item-details-wrapper .woocommerce-loop-product__link .price {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    text-align: left;
}

.shop-loop-item-details-wrapper .add_to_cart_button {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

The point is, that this isn't optimized for mobile phones because I would use a column layout there and don't display the **Add to Cart** button beneath the price.

When you resize the browser to smaller resolutions, you can see, that the price is at some point above the button and this looks not so good.

The problem here is, as I already told above, that the price is a dynamic value with a dynamic length. So you should think about wrapping some pieces of the code into `@media` tags to use at a resolution of x a 2-col layout.

In this case you need to check, when you need to use this. I don't know which prices you have in your shop. So go ahead and enter the biggest price you have and resize the browser. When the item goes over the button, you know the with where you need to use the 2-col layout. So when it's for example at a browser width of `980px`, you need to modify the additional CSS this way to append the 1-col layout only, if the width is bigger than `980px`:

```
@media (min-width: 981px) {
    .shop-loop-item-details-wrapper {
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .shop-loop-item-details-wrapper .woocommerce-loop-product__link {
        margin-right: 8px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 980px) {
    .shop-loop-item-details-wrapper {
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
            -ms-flex-direction: column;
                flex-direction: column;
    }

    .shop-loop-item-details-wrapper .woocommerce-loop-product__link .price {
        margin-bottom: 8px !important;
    }
}

.shop-loop-item-details-wrapper {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 8px;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.shop-loop-item-details-wrapper .woocommerce-loop-product__link {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}

.shop-loop-item-details-wrapper .woocommerce-loop-product__link .price {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    text-align: left;
}

.shop-loop-item-details-wrapper .add_to_cart_button {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Hope it fits you. I've tested it and can confirm that it's working:

[image]

If it works, it would be nice, if you mark this answer as solution and give it a tick up.

Comment: Mr Jo. I added first code to 'functions.php' file of the child theme (nothing happened) and then I added the second css code to 'style.css' file of Child theme (nothing happened). "" -ms-flex-pack: distribute; "" this code is giving ! mark. Where I am making wrong???

Comment: Have you read my answer ( copy the file content-product.php directly into your woocommerce folder of your child theme.)? The the -ms-flex-pack is for older IE browsers ant not supported by the new ones, thats why it's showing a mark. You can ignore the mark.

Comment: Read this to understand what we do (I don't know how much clearer I should explain it to you): https://zemez.io/wordpress/support/how-to/override-woocommerce-template-files/ (take the content-product.php instead of the file taken in the tutorial)

Comment: Mr Jo; I followed your steps. but it didnt work. here is the image link. [link](https://i.postimg.cc/fb3Lm5J7/Screenshot-1.jpg)

Comment: If you've followed my steps, it should looks like on my picture. Have you removed the code from the first answer?

Comment: Yes Mr Jo, I find and followed how to implement your steps and did exactly what you said. 1. First I made woocommerce file at child theme. 2 then I copy the content-productçphp file into this folder. 3. then I replace the php code with your code. 4. then I take your first CSS code and insert to ASdditional CSS and the result screen view is attached at my above messege.

Comment: Do you have a link to your page?

Comment: Please check the DOM in the Developer Tools of your browser, if all of your changes are successfully applied. If you don't know how to do this, you should take some time to understand how a Website is generated, whats a DOM, how you can use the Developer Tools of your browser (which makes your life a lot easier). I've setup a whole new WordPress with Storefront and can confirm, that my changes are working.

Comment: This CSS code show (!) mark at css editor ( -ms-flex-pack: distribute;)

Comment: As I already told above, you can ignore this. It's showing the same on my side..... Please open woocommerce on your dashboard and go to subemnu status. Scroll down and make a screenshot of the last section (Templates).

Comment: Here is the screet shot Mr Jo. [link](https://i.postimg.cc/x1dmcvYY/Screenshot-2.jpg)

Comment: Mr Jo; I guess it is better for me to drop this subject. It will be much more easier for me to change storefront theme.

Comment: Have you checked, if the CSS get's applied to the wrapper we've created in the content-product.php file via the developer tools from your browser??

Comment: Mr Jo it is beyond my current knowladge to check the developer tools. I came this far and showed you my screen how it look. You tried your best and thk you for it but I think I need to change theme.

Comment: If you have absolutely no developer knowledge, you should get rid of any free template. Use for example Divi instead. It supports a drag and drop. But remember, every theme has his limit. So there is no way around to learn a bit of basic development skills.

Comment: Yes definetly, i will continue with elementor and astra-pro Mr.Jo.